# How to return the function result and perform additional operations in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, go, aws-lambda

Suppose I have the following workflow

```
func get_result(event) { return result(event) }
func post_result_operations(event) { /* do some logging */ }
func lambda_handler(event) {
      return get_result(event)
      post_result_operations(event)
}
```

Is there a way to create a lambda function such that I can call the `get_result` function and returns its value and then do the `post_result_operations`. The idea is that I would want to invoke my lambda function through an API and have the function return the result quickly and then do the additional operations after the result is returned. Is there a way to accomplish this in nodejs or Golang. In Golang, we can have something like the following, but I am not sure it will work.

```
func lambda_handler(event) {
     defer post_result_operations(event)
     return get_result(event)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does the second operation run some times, all the time? Is there a condition? One option is to forward the "result" over SQS or SNS. And you have a second Lambda function that responds to those triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is logging you could look into [Lambda extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/using-extensions.html). There is a limited amount of time you can run after the function exits, though.

Once a Lambda function has returned the code is stopped, so anything that might happen after would not happen. The best approach to this is to make your processing asynchronous, via something like SQS. You can sned the event on to an SQS queue where a different Lambda function can process it, and then return your result. Something like this:

```golang
func get_result(event) { return result(event) }
func send_to_sqs(event) { /* send the message to SQS */ }
func lambda_handler(event) {
      send_to_sqs(event)
      return get_result(event)
}
```

Comment: How does one trigger a lambda function on an SQS event? I am familiar with lambda triggers on SNS events but not with SQS. If possible with SQS, is it faster to use SNS or SQS?

Comment: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html). If you only intend to have one recipient of the message I'd send it to SQS. If you want to allow more than one recipient then SNS works. SQS does allow some batching on the Lambda, which SNS does not. Quite often you'd go SNS -> SQS -> Lambda if you go that route.